# Shrinking Mean with Noisy and Skewed Dataset

Tags: bayesian, mean, inference, gamma-distribution, skewness

I am having difficulty inferring the proper measure of central tendency in a noisy, right skewed dataset. The mean for each group is higher than is expected and the coefficient of variation is very high (sometimes 2+).

If I infer a value that is overstated, there are business penalties because client goals will not be achieved. However, I do not want to underestimate the value because it would undervalue the group's ability.

For example: how do I find the most likely central value of the following sample when the mean is 1,861 and the median is 225?

```
19533, 19395, 11723, 9998, 9584, 8499, 8438, 8005, 7234, 6667, 6313, 5472, 4819, 4484, 4031, 4018, 3863, 3320, 2640, 1928, 1188, 1089, 1046, 906, 842, 790, 547, 484, 484, 463, 441, 381, 318, 302, 301, 296, 287, 270, 268, 256, 249, 241, 239, 239, 227, 223, 223, 215, 213, 202, 193, 187, 181, 178, 173, 173, 170, 165, 156, 149, 145, 136, 133, 130, 128, 126, 119, 117, 111, 107, 104, 100, 91, 90, 84, 80, 79, 78, 78, 75, 70, 68, 66, 64, 63, 60, 59, 48, 42, 0
```

The example uses one group, but I have over 200 other groups. Below is an image of the density distribution of means for each group (blue) with a Gamma (red) and Normal (yellow) distribution density overlayed:

[image]

```
 ggplot(variance_table, aes(x=mean)) + 
     geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="black", fill="white", bins=50) +
     stat_density(colour="blue", geom="line", position="identity") +
     stat_function(fun=dnorm, args=list(mean=mean(variance_table$mean), sd=sd(variance_table$mean)), color = "yellow") + 
     stat_function(fun=dgamma, args=list(shape=mean(variance_table$mean)^2/sd(variance_table$mean)^2, scale=sd(variance_table$mean)^2/mean(variance_table$mean)), color="red")
```

I've tried Bayesian mean shrinkage using a Gamma prior, but the shrinkage estimators only shrink the mean at most 11%. I want to produce a more reliable statistic that balances between not overstating and also not understating the most likely value.

I would appreciate any ideas or techniques to determine the central tendency for each group.

**EDIT:**
If it adds context I would prefer a method to estimate the probability of reaching the mean given the prior distribution. Example: there is a 80% probability that the next observation will reach the mean given the prior distribution of 200+ groups.

Comment: When you refer to "most likely value" in your penultimate paragraph, do you mean :) that you really want to estimate the mode?

Comment: Not necessarily the mode because I am dealing with continuous data that can take a wide range of values. I want to estimate the central tendency so I don't overestimate or underestimate the performance of a sample.